# Missing data in c# query window from oracle database

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, odp.net

I have an oracle database. I connected to the database with odac (ODP.NET) and in query window I made an easy test:

`select * from abc.groups;`

after I check this in Toad for Oracle.

The query window contains 192 record, and the toad contains 352 records.

I tried to find some special lines, for example:

```
select*from abc.groups where id=15;
```

I couldn't find anything in query window, but I found it in toad. 
There is a same database, same log in details.
In C# the date handling is not always correct where is the problem?

Comment: What does date handling have to do with it?

Comment: I'm not so sure you are actually connected to the same database. Try whatever the select command is for Oracle that returns the server and database names and compare those instead of results from abc.groups.

Comment: Saying **abc**.groups, you are selecting from table GROUPS which belongs to user ABC. Is ABC user you're connected to in both TOAD and your C# application?

Comment: I checked some same lines in toad and c#

for example ATG_ID is same, and the name, but in toad ATG_US_ID is 331, and in c# ATG_US_ID is 332 in same line.

Comment: Littlefoot:
Yes, I connected same, there are same lines, for example the 15. line is same in toad and c#, but the 16. line is different (same data in few columns but date column is different)
And some rows absolutely missing

Comment: Matthew Evans:
There is a same row, same data but the date is different in the row. In c# it's always 11/5/2017